# How can i find what GPO is applying a proxy

Tags: windows, group-policy

I was asked recently if I could stop my boss having his proxy settings automatically applied.
Our proxy settings are set by group policy so I figured it should be easy to determine which GPO it is and simply remove him from the group that the GPO scope uses to apply it.

Our group policy is quite complex with quite a few different GPO's being applied to a variety of users and computers.

The question is then how can I find the GPO where the setting is being applied without having to go through each one and determine if it applies to his user / computer account?

I've run through the Group Policy Modelling wizard for both his user account and the computer (just in case), but I can't find anything specific to him. The only GPO that has anything to do with proxy settings is in a user OU which his account isn't in. i.e. the GPO is applying to Domain Users\Users and his account is in Domain Users\IT.

Any ideas? Is there a tool that can better tell me what settings are being set on his account ? Can it be interrogated via powershell?

Comment: If its not applied with GPO, have a look at WPAD! - can you reach: http://wpad/wpad.dat ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `gpresult /h c:\temp\policy.htm` on the target computer to get the resultant policy.
You can also run it remotely using **psexec** (with cmd command) or **Powershell**.

Another option is to run **rsop.msc** on the target computer.

Note: both gpresult and rsop should be done under the affected user to collect the policies applied to his account.

In Powershell you need to use either commandlet **Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy** with parameters
**-Computer**  and **-User**

```
Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -user someuser -computer contoso.com\computer-08 -reporttype html -path c:\reports\UserAndComputerReport.html
```

> Note:  to run the Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy cmdlet, you must start
> Windows PowerShell with elevated rights

or use the following Powershell code utilizing COM object:

```
$OutputFile = “C:\Temp\GPOExport.html”
$ComputerName = “test.contoso.com”
$UserName = “john”
$gpm = New-Object -ComObject GPMgmt.GPM
$constants = $gpm.GetConstants()

$gpmRSOP = $GPM.GetRSOP($Constants.RSOPModeLogging,$null,0)
$gpmRSOP.LoggingComputer = $ComputerName
$gpmRSOP.LoggingUser = $UserName

$gpmRSOP.CreateQueryResults()
$gpmRSOP.GenerateReportToFile($constants.ReportHTML,$outputfile)
```